# Hibernate is trying to insert an optional @OneToOne empty field

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, one-to-one

Fellows,

I'm facing an issue during hibernate storing with merge() method. Let me see if you can help me. Having said that, I'll post my code below.

## 1) DDL SQL

Here is the involved table defs (some columns were ommited because are only regular data):

```
TABLE proposta (
    idProposta INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    idBeneficio INT(11) NOT NULL,
    idTabela INT NULL,
    idOperacao INT NOT NULL,
    ...


TABLE conta_bancaria (
    idContaBancaria INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    idBanco INT NOT NULL,
    idProposta INT NOT NULL,
    idBeneficio INT NOT NULL,
    ...



TABLE banco (
    idBanco INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nmNomeBanco VARCHAR(60) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    cdBanco VARCHAR(5) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    nmNomeCompleto VARCHAR(90) NULL,
    dsSite VARCHAR(256) NULL,
    blAtivo INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`idBanco`)
```

## 2) Code

### 2.1) Entity Mappings

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Proposta")
public class Proposta extends GenericEntity<Proposta>{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idProposta")
    private Integer idProposta;


    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="proposta", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional=true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idProposta", referencedColumnName="idProposta")
    @Basic(optional=true)
    private ContaBancaria contaRecebimento;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idBeneficio", referencedColumnName="idBeneficio")
    private Beneficio beneficio;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)  
    @JoinColumn(name = "idOperacao", referencedColumnName="idOperacao")
    private Operacao operacao;
    ...



@Entity
@Table(name="Conta_Bancaria")
public class ContaBancaria extends GenericEntity<ContaBancaria>{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idContaBancaria")
    private Integer idContaBancaria;


    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idBanco")
    private Banco banco;

    @OneToOne  
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn 
    private Proposta proposta;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Beneficio beneficio;
    ...
```

### 2.2) Controller

```
@ManagedBean("propostaBean")
@ViewScoped
public class PropostaBean extends GenericController {

    @Inject
    private PropostaService propostaService; 


/** Aba Cadastro Proposta **/
private Pessoa pessoa;
private Beneficio beneficio;
private Proposta proposta;

private List<Banco> bancos;
private Integer idBancoSelected;

private Integer idOperacaoSelected;
private List<Operacao> operacoes;



public PropostaBean() {
    refreshBean();
}

@PostConstruct
private void refreshBean(){
    this.pessoa = new Pessoa();
    this.beneficio = new Beneficio();
    this.proposta = new Proposta();
    this.filtroBenProp = new FiltroBeneficioProposta();
    this.resultadoBuscaBeneficio = new ArrayList<PessoaBeneficioDTO>();
    this.bancos = new ArrayList<Banco>();
    this.operacoes = new ArrayList<Operacao>();
}

public String salvarProposta(){
    String method = "salvarProposta";
    long startTime = startMethod(method);

    Banco banco = null;
    for (Banco b : bancos) {
        if(b.getIdBanco() == idBancoSelected){
            banco = b;
        }
    }

    Operacao operacao = null;
    for (Operacao op : operacoes) {
        if(op.getIdOperacao() == idOperacaoSelected){
            operacao = op;
            this.proposta.setOperacao(operacao);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Operacao = ["+operacao+"], idOperacaoSelected ["+idOperacaoSelected+"]");
    System.out.println("Conta Bancaria = ["+proposta.getContaRecebimento()+"]");
    this.proposta.setBeneficio(beneficio);
    try {
        if(proposta.getContaRecebimento().getAgencia() == null){
            proposta.setContaRecebimento(null);
        }
        this.proposta = propostaService.salvarProposta(proposta);
        proposta.setContaRecebimento(new ContaBancaria());
        FacesUIHelper.addSucessMessage("Proposta no ["+proposta.getNpi()+"] cadastrada com sucesso");
    } catch (BusinessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        FacesUIHelper.addErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
    }

    leaveMethod(startTime, method);
    return "/views/cadastro/cadastroProposta";
}
}
```

### 2.3) Service

```
@Service("propostaService")
@Transactional
public class PropostaServiceImpl extends GenericServiceImpl<Proposta> implements Serializable, PropostaService {

public static final String USUARIO_DEFAULT = "SYSTEM";

@Inject
private PropostaDAO<Proposta> propostaDAO;

@Inject
private OperacaoDAO<Operacao> operacaoDAO;

@Inject
private BeneficioDAO<Beneficio> beneficioDAO;

@Inject
private TipoOperacaoDAO<TipoOperacao> tipoOperacaoDAO;

@Inject 
private ParametroSistemaDAO<ParametroSistema> parametroSistemaDAO;

@Override
public Proposta salvarProposta(Proposta p) throws BusinessException {
    String method = "salvarProposta";
    long startTime = startMethod(method);
    Proposta prop = null;
    if(p.getIdProposta() == null){
        try {
            Integer npi = parametroSistemaDAO.getSequenceValue("SEQ_NPI");
            p.setNpi(npi);
            Date dt = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
            p.setDataProposta(dt);
            p.setDataStatus(dt);
            p.setStatus(Proposta.CADASTRADA);
            p.setUsuarioResponsavel(USUARIO_DEFAULT);
            prop = propostaDAO.saveOrUpdate(p);
        } catch (DAOException e) {
            throw new BusinessException(e);
        }
    }else {
        prop = propostaDAO.saveOrUpdate(p);
    }
    leaveMethod(startTime, method);
    return prop;
}
}
```

### 2.4) DAO

```
@Repository("genericDao")
public abstract class GenericDAOImpl<T> implements GenericDAO<T> {

protected static Logger logger;

@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager entityManager;

protected String className;
private Class< T > type;

public GenericDAOImpl() {
    Type t = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
    ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) t;
    type = (Class) pt.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    this.logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
    this.className = this.getClass().getName();
}

@Transactional
public T save(T entity) throws DAOException {
    entityManager.persist(entity);
    return entity;
}

@Transactional
public T update(T entity) {
    entityManager.merge(entity);
    return entity;
}

@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public T saveOrUpdate(T entity){
    entityManager.merge(entity);
    return entity;
}

@Transactional
public Collection<T> saveOrUpdateAll(Collection<T> entities) {
    for(T element: entities) {
        entityManager.merge(element);
    }
    return entities;
}

@Transactional
public void delete(T entity) {
    entityManager.remove(entity);
}

@Transactional
public void deleteAll(List<T> list) {
    for(T element: list) {
        entityManager.remove(element);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<T> listAll() {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<T> c = cb.createQuery(type);

    Root<T> genericObject = c.from(type);
    TypedQuery<T> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(c);

    List<T> resultList = (List<T>) typedQuery.getResultList();

    return resultList;
}

public T findById(long id) {
    T result =(T) entityManager.find(type, id);
    return result;
}

public T findById(Serializable id) {
    T result =(T) entityManager.find(type, id);
    return result;
}

public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return entityManager;
}

public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}
}
```

When I call merge for proposta instance (which is not created yet), even when I mark (or at least it supposed to be marked) Proposta.ContaBancaria as an optional relationship, hibernate tries to insert it also. Here it's hibernate logs:

```
04:47:33,410 INFO  [stdout] Hibernate: 
04:47:33,410 INFO  [stdout]     insert 
04:47:33,411 INFO  [stdout]     into
04:47:33,411 INFO  [stdout]         Proposta
04:47:33,411 INFO  [stdout]         (idBeneficio, dtEnvioFisico, dtPagamento,     dtPagamentoComissao, dtProposta, dtStatus, cdDocExterno, tpMeioPagamento, cdNpi, nrLinhasAtual, nrNumParcelas, idOperacao, status, nmUsuario, vlBrutoConsiderado, vlDescontos, vlLiquidoLiberado, vlLiquidoBeneficio, vlMargemLivre, vlValorParcela) 
04:47:33,413 INFO  [stdout]     values
04:47:33,413 INFO  [stdout]         (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

04:47:33,502 INFO  [stdout] Hibernate: 
04:47:33,502 INFO  [stdout]     insert 
04:47:33,502 INFO  [stdout]     into
04:47:33,503 INFO  [stdout]         Conta_Bancaria
04:47:33,503 INFO  [stdout]         (nrAgencia, blAtivo, idBanco, nrDigitoAgencia,     nrDigitoConta, nrConta, blPoupanca, nrTipo) 
04:47:33,504 INFO  [stdout]     values
04:47:33,504 INFO  [stdout]         (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Then I get this error following:

```
04:47:33,552 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000
04:47:33,553 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] Column 'idBanco' cannot be null
04:47:34,352 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] #{propostaBean.salvarProposta}: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException:   Column 'idBanco' cannot be null; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Column 'idBanco' cannot be null: javax.faces.FacesException: #{propostaBean.salvarProposta}: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Column 'idBanco' cannot be null; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Column 'idBanco' cannot be null
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at org.primefaces.application.DialogActionListener.processAction(DialogActionListener.java:45) [primefaces-4.0.jar:4.0]
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1093) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:98) [primefaces-4.0.jar:4.0]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Column 'idBanco' cannot be null; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Column 'idBanco' cannot be null
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
... 26 more

Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Column 'idBanco' cannot be null; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Column 'idBanco' cannot be null
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:188) [spring-orm-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:154) [spring-orm-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:417) [spring-orm-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59) [spring-tx-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213) [spring-tx-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147) [spring-tx-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) [spring-tx-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262) [spring-tx-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95) [spring-tx-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) [spring-aop-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy110.saveOrUpdate(Unknown Source)
at br.com.centralemprestimos.sisat.service.PropostaServiceImpl.salvarProposta(PropostaServiceImpl.java:65) [classes:]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) [spring-aop-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) [spring-tx-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) [spring-tx-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262) [spring-tx-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95) [spring-tx-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) [spring-aop-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy113.salvarProposta(Unknown Source)
at br.com.centralemprestimos.sisat.mbean.PropostaBean.salvarProposta(PropostaBean.java:184) [classes:]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:262) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
... 27 more

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Column 'idBanco' cannot be null
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:74) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy78.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:55) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2757) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3268) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:78) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:272) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:304) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:195) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:128) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3MergeEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3MergeEventListener.java:71) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.saveTransientEntity(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:422) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.mergeTransientEntity(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:342) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:304) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:259) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:790) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:774) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingAction$6.cascade(CascadingAction.java:288) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:380) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:323) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:208) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:165) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:462) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.mergeTransientEntity(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:395) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:304) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:259) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:86) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:781) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:766) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:770) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:867) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:257) [spring-orm-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy102.merge(Unknown Source)
at br.com.mobinn.fmwk.persistence.GenericDAOImpl.saveOrUpdate(GenericDAOImpl.java:60) [classes:]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) [spring-aop-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) [spring-tx-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
... 59 more

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'idBanco' cannot be null
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.26.jar:]
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.26.jar:]
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1041) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.26.jar:]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4190) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.26.jar:]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4122) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.26.jar:]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2570) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.26.jar:]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2731) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.26.jar:]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2818) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.26.jar:]
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2157) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.26.jar:]
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2460) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.26.jar:]
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2377) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.26.jar:]
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2361) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.26.jar:]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
... 106 more
```

But it shouldn't be inserting ContaBancaria because it's empty and optional. It's not null because it's being rendered in view, but all fields are empty as this print shows:

```
04:47:33,145 INFO  [stdout] Conta Bancaria = [ContaBancaria [idContaBancaria=null, agencia=, digitoAgencia=null, numeroConta=null, digitoConta=, tipo=null, poupanca=0, ativo=null]]
```

Is there any mapping errors ? What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your working with a new entity the code should call `persist` instead of `merge`.  Could you provide the full entities and sql tables?

Comment: Done. The context where i call it is on salvarPoroposta(). Thanks.

Comment: Please let me know if there is something missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your mapping, you specified the property cascade with value Cascade.All, which means the ContaBancaria must be inserted/updated/deleted in cascade when the parent entity Proposta is inserted/updated/deleted.  The optional attribute set to "true" means that ContaBancaria field in Proposta can be null when inserting or updating, but given that in your case ContaBancaria is not null (but empty), hibernate understands that there is an object (not null) to insert in cascade.